Visual Studio puts up Update Solution Filter warning even if nothing changed
I've setup a solution filter for an all c# solution to cut down on compile time.  And it works great for that purpose.  However, pretty much every time I get latest from git, it hits me with "Additional Projects Loaded/Unloaded in Solution Filter. Update Solution Filter" warning.

Nothing has changed.  Out of curiosity I copied the .slnf file elsewhere and then compared the changes after I click Update Solution Filter link.  Absolutely nothing changed. Still the same file.
Is this a bug, of am I using the solution filters wrong or am I missing something obvious, like a setting?
